# Issue with navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am presenting a navigation controller with a view controller initialized as its root using `presentModalViewController`. However, when I push another view controller onto this new navigation stack, the back button needs to be pushed twice to return to the original view presented modally. Any idea why this would occur? Is it possible that the new view controller is being pushed onto the original navigation controller and then the navigation controller in the modal view controller as well?

My code in the original navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addViewController];  
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[addViewController release];
[navController release];
```

And then my code inside the modal view:

```
PriorityViewController *priorityView = [[PriorityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PriorityView" bundle:nil];
priorityView.taskInfo = self.taskInfo;
priorityView.isAdding = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:priorityView animated:YES];
[priorityView release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. I was handling the view controllers, and the navigation controller just fine. But was using a table view to push the new controllers onto the navigation controller stack. And the switch statement handling the row selection in my table view was missing a break statement, so two cases were being called instead of just one meant for that row, if that makes any sense.

Comment: So it was broken because you didn't "break" it?  :-)

Comment: Haha, that is a great pun. And this is the only forum it would be appreciated in. :) As long it's working, I can laugh

Comment: In life, you can laugh, or you can cry.  Everyone must choose.

Answer (score 0):

You have two navigation stacks - you are presenting a **navigation controller** modally.

Just use one, like this:

```
 [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addViewController animated:YES];
 [addViewController release];
```

Comment: For some reason, it thinks I am presenting a different view controller than the one I am creating. I have a SpecificsViewController that I push, and a TitleViewController that I push, and a DurationViewController that I push, all in that same view, with no issue. But the PriorityViewController gets messed up. And the console seems to think I am pushing the SpecificsViewController instead of the PriorityViewController.